# detect double extension with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

hey i'm trying to detect a double extension filename with javascript but still can not figure out how i can get just the extension with this code

```
var ext = file.name.split('.').pop()
```

and it work fine but i want to detect if file has as name `.js.png` it will give me just ".png" so it will show the progress bar  how to stop this

Comment: `/\.\w{2,3}\.\w{2,3}$/.test(filename)`

Comment: @Tushar thank you very much it works fine now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it has more than 1 extension.

```
    var ext = file.name.split('.');

    if(ext.length > 2) {
        console.log("found");
    }
    ext[1]; // first extension
    ext[2]; // second extension
```